# EXE using Pytorch and packed with PyInstaller cannot run on the other PC

Tags: python, windows, exe, pytorch, pyinstaller

I built an exe of a program using pytorch. It works well on the PC where the exe was built on but not on the other PC. An ImportError raised, DLL load failed.

I'm new to pytorch and pyinstaller so I can't get what happend.

The ImportError:

```
F:\test>test D:\testData.xml D:\testResult.xml
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\jre\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\runtime\win64;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin;D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\polyspace\bin;D:\FFMPEG\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Anaconda3;D:\Anaconda3\Scripts;D:\Anaconda3;D:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;D:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;D:\Anaconda3\Scripts;D:\Python\Python36\Scripts\;D:\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\snow-\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Program Files\modeltech64_10.4\win64;D:\modeltech64_10.4\win64;D:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\win32pe_edu;F:\test;F:\test\torch\lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yuech\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\cy_pytorch\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
[10812] Failed to execute script test
```

I print all the 'PATH'

the line 6 is

```
import torch
```

the line 102 is

```
from torch._C import *
```

I searched on internet and I found it might be caused by openmp or numpy. I checked and I do have them in the folder.

I tried to add variable environment 'PATH' but it doesn't work.

I use pytorch 1.0.1, python 3.6.8 and pyinstaller 3.4

I built my exe with this line

```
pyinstaller test.py --exclude-module PyQt5 -p dataLoader_cy.py --hidden-import dataLoader_cy -p C:\Users\yuech\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\cy_pytorch\Lib\site-packages --hidden-import
 torchvision --hidden-import numpy
```

I tried adding the environment variable with this

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += (";" + os.path.abspath('.'))
os.environ['PATH'] += (";" + os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), "torch\lib"))
```

Since my experience in python and pytorch is limited, I can' get why it can work on one PC but not on the others. I want my exe works on the other windows. Please help me if you have some idea. Thank you!

Comment: It may also be a problem of dlls inclusion, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293036/exe-made-from-python-file-which-uses-tensorflow-gpu-does-not-use-gpu-when-deploy/74814428#74814428

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know the source of the problem, but thanks to @raviv [post](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2666#issuecomment-508013383), you can workaroud it (works for me) by installing pytorch with pip in conda:

1. `conda uninstall pytorch`
2. `pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
3. `pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torchvision-0.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
4. `pyinstaller test.py --exclude-module PyQt5 -p dataLoader_cy.py --hidden-import dataLoader_cy -p C:\Users\yuech\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\cy_pytorch\Lib\site-packages --hidden-import
   torchvision --hidden-import numpy`

Or installing conda cudatoolkit (I didn't try it).

Making an .exe in plain Python (outside of conda) and installing pytorch with pip didn't work for me.

All credits to @raviv [raviv](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2666#issuecomment-508013383)